# Difference b/w connecting to SQL Server from ASP.net and Desktop application In terms on CAL?

Tags: windows, sql-server, asp.net, licensing, desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

- Why purchasing a Client Access
  License (CAL) for every device that
  accesses your server is not needed in
  web?
- If I have a CAL for 10 devices and I
  need one more device to connect to
  SQL Server, can I do this using Web
  service?
- I have asked this question on
  StackOverflow and a part of one
  answer is this; *"In the case of web
  servers/services, the number of CALs
  required is tied to the distinct
  end-users/devices"* Can you explain
  this a little.
- If I have 10 CAL of SQL Server and
  there are 11 user using my website
  and connects with SQL Server
  simultaneously then why I don't need
  11th CAL?
- **SQL Server 2005**

Comment: We'll need to know what version of SQL you're running as the licensing has changed several times over the years.

Comment: SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 4):

I'll answer each bullet-point separately from above:

1. If you are using a CAL model, you DO need a CAL for every distinct end-user or device that accesses your server (there is both a [user-CAL model](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/licensing.aspx#SPuser) and a [device-CAL model](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/licensing.aspx#SPdevice))
2. If you are asking if there is a way to basically dynamically/programatically increase the number of CALs assigned to your server, the answer is no. There actually is no license-management tool at all with Sql Server 2005+ (so far) - the license management model is a model called *'integrity'* (i.e. you are responsible for being an ethical user of the software and properly licensing the server). This can be a bit different if you have a software-assurance or enterprise-agreement with Microsoft, but it's basically the same.
3. I was the one who answered it on StackOverflow - what this means is that you need a user or device CAL license for either *every distinct user* **OR** *every distinct device (i.e. laptop, computer, server, phone, etc.)*. In a web-facing environment (i.e. you have a website exposed to the internet, or to hundreds/thousands of users on an intranet), you would need a CAL for every single user or device that accessed your web site. The CALs are NOT tied to the web-servers themselves, they would need to be tied to the end-users of the website(s) in question (this is called [multiplexing](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/special-considerations.aspx#multiplexing) and in no way reduces the number of CALs required for licensing properly).
4. In this case, you ***DO*** need 11 CALs, however the server will not explicitly force this upon you (see the answer to #2 above, this is the integrity part).

That should cover each question I hope. Note that in terms of #3, if you are using a website that is exposed to the internet and/or a large number of users/devices (large being likely anything in excess of ~20 in this case), you likely want to research the [processor licensing model](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/licensing.aspx#processor) instead.  A few good references for Sql licensing:

- [Special Considerations](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/special-considerations.aspx) (covers multi-core, virtualization, multiplexing, etc.)
- [Licensing options](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/licensing.aspx)
- [Licensing FAQs](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/pricing-licensing-faq.aspx)

Comment: The per CPU and multiplexing of SQL cals often trip folks up. Good summary.